# Method invocation may produce java NullpointerException in Button click listener

Tags: java, android, invocation

I want to open just make a toast when user click on button it is very simplest thing but i cant do it :| method innovation may produce java NullpointerException warning occurred and toast didn't show

```
public class TrackingRecord extends AppCompatActivity {
 GPSTracker  gps;
ArrayList<String> cordsList= new ArrayList<String>();
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tracking_record);

    //decelartions
    TextView tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_set1);
    TextView tv2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_set2);
    TextView tv3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_set3);
    Button ST=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ST) ;


    Log.i("Finall", "AndroidGPSTrackingActivity-> ");
    ST.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"HIIIIIIIIII",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });



    }
}
```

following warning shows

> Method invocation 'ST.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                      @Override public void onC...' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I also check this but when i do this toast didnot show

Comment: check the `ST` and replace `getApplicationContext()` with `TrackingRecord .this`.